# What are these black bugs attached to the guava tree?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, bugs

What are these black bugs attached to the guava tree? They are attached to branches and leaves. Do they harm the tree? Should I try to get rid of this? If so how? (This is in Sydney, Australia)
[image]

[image]

Comment: That's scale. They move to get there, but stay put forever. Sucking the life out of our babies. Scrape off and spray with soap or neem oil. Inspect more often.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Any harm in leaving them on the tree?

Comment: They will multiply forever and kill the tree.